# Java 8: Convert file time (milliseconds from 1970) to RFC 1123 format

Tags: java, java-8

This seems like it should be simple, but so far nothing I try is working. Basically I want to convert a file time in milliseconds from 1970 (the usual) to a TemporalAccessor and then to an [RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123) formatted string. However, while I can get examples that compile, I get runtime errors. For example:

```
// Just using 0 milliseconds time for quick and easy test
System.out.println(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME.format(
                FileTime.from(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).toInstant()));
```

results in

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException:
> Unsupported field: DayOfMonth

I have tried a few variations of this using different classes (Instant, LocalTime, Date), but I get the same result.

What is the proper way to do this?

UPDATE:
The original question has been technically answered and I realized I needed to be more specific. I had already 'successfully' converted milliseconds to a TemporalAccessor myself, however it didn't seem like this object was in usable state.  I got a run time error when trying to use it to do what I really needed, which made me believe I hadn't created it properly. That something was missing. Either that or there is a bug in the RFC 1123 formatter.

UPDATE 2:
Thanks to Sleafar for posting a working answer.

Using his example I did it slightly differently since for some reason I really wanted a 'complete' TemporalAccessor to do stuff with. Here is a working example:

```
TemporalAccessor time = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(0),
ZoneId.systemDefault());
System.out.println(
        java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME.format(time));
```

Comment: Why not use `Instant.ofEpochMilli()`?

Comment: I did. It was the first thing I tried. Same exception.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Instant` type doesn't contain timezone information. You can define a timezone for the formatter like this:

```
System.out.println(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME
    .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).format( FileTime.from(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).toInstant()));
```

Edit:

Actually there are reasons to have formatters without an assigned timezone, as well as date/time representing classes. Consider the following example:

```
ZoneId ect = ZoneId.of(ZoneId.SHORT_IDS.get("ECT"));

DateTimeFormatter f1 = DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME;
DateTimeFormatter f2 = f1.withZone(ect);
DateTimeFormatter f3 = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME;
DateTimeFormatter f4 = f3.withZone(ect);

LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(2015, 07, 21, 0, 0, 0, 0);
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(ldt, ect);
Instant ins = zdt.toInstant();

System.out.println(f1.format(ins)); // throws exception (1)
System.out.println(f2.format(ins)); // Tue, 21 Jul 2015 00:00:00 +0200
System.out.println(f3.format(ins)); // throws exception (2)
System.out.println(f4.format(ins)); // 2015-07-21T00:00:00

System.out.println(f1.format(zdt)); // Tue, 21 Jul 2015 00:00:00 +0200
System.out.println(f2.format(zdt)); // Tue, 21 Jul 2015 00:00:00 +0200
System.out.println(f3.format(zdt)); // 2015-07-21T00:00:00
System.out.println(f4.format(zdt)); // 2015-07-21T00:00:00

System.out.println(f1.format(ldt)); // throws exception (3)
System.out.println(f2.format(ldt)); // throws exception (4)
System.out.println(f3.format(ldt)); // 2015-07-21T00:00:00
System.out.println(f4.format(ldt)); // 2015-07-21T00:00:00

ZoneId hst = ZoneId.of(ZoneId.SHORT_IDS.get("HST"));
ZonedDateTime zdt2 = ZonedDateTime.of(ldt, hst);

System.out.println(f1.format(zdt2)); // Tue, 21 Jul 2015 00:00:00 -1000
System.out.println(f2.format(zdt2)); // Tue, 21 Jul 2015 12:00:00 +0200
System.out.println(f3.format(zdt2)); // 2015-07-21T00:00:00
System.out.println(f4.format(zdt2)); // 2015-07-21T12:00:00
```

- `Instant` represents an actual point in time without referring to a specific location and therefore without a timezone. The exceptions (1) and (2) are raised because to represent the specific point in time the formatter needs a timezone to make the output readable for humans.
- `ZonedDateTime` represents an actual point in time also assigned to a specific timezone. No problems at all to format them, but consider the last example. If you set a timezone in the formatter, you might get different results.
- `LocalDateTime` doesn't represent an actual point in time. You can even assign a value which is invalid in some timezones, like when the clock is pushed forward 1 hour in case of daylight saving time. To get a real point in time you have to combine it with a timezone (like done in the example above). Exceptions (3) and (4) are raised, because the formatter wants to print a timezone value, which doesn't exist in this type.

I can't tell why the designers opted to discover the described problems at runtime instead of compile time. Maybe it would make the class hierarchy too complicated.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected it was something like that. It's disappointing to me that It doesn't use the system default time by default. Oh well.

Comment: Time, without a timezone, is meaningless. I see no good reason to not use system default timezone as the default timezone since 'most likely' that's what the user intended (if they don't specify a timezone). I definitely can't see a good justification for throwing a runtime exception instead. IMO, that was a terrible design decision.

Answer (score 1):

Milliseconds since 1970 is known as "epoch time", and Instant has the static method [`Instant.ofEpochMilli(long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochMilli-long-) to support creation from a `long` number of milliseconds. Conceptually Instant represents a single moment (`long` seconds + `int` nanoseconds) in "the standard Java epoch", so representing file time as an Instant is the correct JSR-310 way to do it.

FileTime also has a [`fromMillis(long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/FileTime.html#fromMillis-long-) static method for the same purpose.

In this case, the conversion wasn't the problem—it was the lack of timezone as Sleafar identified first, as reflected in your edited question.

Comment: This gave me the same exception.  Did you try it?  System.out.println(
    java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME.format(Instant.ofEpochMilli(0)));

Comment: I was answering the original question directly; thank you for updating it to make it easier for others to find. I've edited my answer to highlight Sleafar's correct diagnosis.

Comment: Yes and thank you. It was my fault for not being more specific. I really wanted to create a TemporalAccessor that was 'complete' and wouldn't generate runtime exceptions. That fact that the new time classes were implemented this way seems pretty appalling, but maybe that's just me.

Answer (score 1):

The conversion to Instant succeeds without problem. The problem is the formatter. Use ISO_INSTANT formatter instead of RFC_1123_DATE_TIME then you should go:

```
        inst = Instant.now();
        System.out.println(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT
                           .format( inst ) );
```

--> 2015-07-20T21:11:53.001Z

If you really want to have RFC_1123 format, you have to declare a timezone.

Either append it to the formatter :

```
        System.out.println(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME
                           .withZone( ZoneOffset.UTC )
                           .format( inst ) );
```

or convert the Instant to a ZonedDateTime:

```
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( inst, ZoneOffset.UTC );
        System.out.println(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME
                           .format( zdt ) );
```

--> Mon, 20 Jul 2015 21:11:53 GMT

Comment: Except ISO_INSTANT doesn't produce the correct format I need. I really do need RFC 1123 compliant formatting.

Comment: Maybe it's a bug. I can accept that. But somehow I think there is a way to do this and I just haven't initialized it correctly. It needs an explicit time zone or something.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, what I really want is a way to create a TemporalAccessor that was 'complete'. I wasn't clear enough about this, but partly that is because I didn't know why it was failing in the first place (i.e. that it was incomplete). I really don't like this idea of throwing runtime exceptions for what 'seem' like perfectly good instances. Why didn't they use the system default time zone? Not sure why they did it that way.